# npm list only dev or prod depedencies

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to `ls` only the production dependencies from `package.json` following the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)

So I am doing

`npm list -depth 0 -prod`

or

`npm list -depth 0 -only prod`

[image]

But npm seems to ignore it and it lists both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`

**Any idea how I can achieve that?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found out that the command is not supported on `3.7.3` so I updated my npm version to `3.8.7` and the following command does the job

`npm list -prod -depth 0`

Answer (score 8):

`npm list -depth 0 -prod true` Lists the dependencies and `npm list -depth 0 -dev true` lists the devDependencies. Those work for me. You are missing the `true` after the `-prod` or `-dev` flag.

Comment: unfortunately doesnt work for me http://i.giphy.com/3o6ozziJEA8OmANpcY.gif for the `prod`, it should display only lodash and rx

Comment: Ok, I found it out that I had an old version of npm, `true` is not required

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here  confused by the google recommendations. Currently (2023) npm can list only the production dependencies with `npm --omit=dev` (npm >=8). If you want to list the `dev` dependecies only, there is no option (no `--omit=production/prod`), but you can do something like this in bash:

```
npm ls --depth=0 | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | grep -vxF -f <(npm ls --omit=dev --depth=0 | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
```

the `awk` part is to use only the name of the packages and not the extra formatting added by `npm ls`.