# How to use "yarn" or "npm" to list specific type of dependencies

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

While developing a package, we need a way to know if package "x" exist in `peer` or `dev` dependencies, I'm trying

```sh
npm ls --omit dev # to list peers deps
```

and tried

```sh
yarn list --dev # to list dev deps
```

I didn't succeed in any of them.

Can someone help to solve this with a simple `npm` or `yarn` command?

Comment: You should use `npm list -dev -depth 0`. Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826372/npm-list-only-dev-or-prod-depedencies)

Comment: Okay, but how to list peers dependencies too?

Comment: I guess you drop the -depth 0 flag, but I will test it later.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure, if it is possible with a single npm command. You can list the peer dependencies of a single package using `npm info <your-package> peerDepencencies`

Comment: Unfortunately no, didn't work and if it was trying to check the global npm I can't make use of it because I want it to work locally before publishing the package

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `project file is not configured/missing the dependencies` when you added them. Regardless, there are two steps to this, create the dependency and then; move it to `peerDependencies` listed below.

Also please share your project file for future questions

> First you **need to create those dependencies** in your project (*explained below* #2)

> Second/Then NPM/Yarn can leverage that and give the correct results when you list.

---

## *Step 1:* How to create those dependencies

> `npm i @angular/core`

- This will add a property in your project file

---

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0"
}
```

---

- Now, after installing, move the installed package name to `peerDependencies` section.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0"
}
```

## *Step 2:* How to list peer dependency, please *replace* react-native with your package

```
// for peer dependencies on a package & specific release
npm info react-native@latest peerDependencies

// for peer dependencies on a package *** replace react-native with your package
npm info react-native peerDependencies
```

---

```
// for production dependencies 
npm list -dev -depth 0

// or with flags
npm list -depth 0 -prod true
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can write a Node.js script that does `require('./package.json')` and inspect the resulting object's `dependencies`, `peerDependencies`, and `devDependencies` values.

This won't tell you if they're actually installed yet or not, and it won't tell you about transitive dependencies.

`npm` offers ways to omit dev and peer dependencies from `npm ls` but not production dependencies, and I imagine that might be the issue you're running into. This is a clunky workaround for that.

Once you've done this to get a list of peer and dev dependencies, you can use `child_process` to run `npm ls` on each to see if they are actually installed.

This is not an elegant solution, but if nothing else is working, it should at least work.

```
> require('./package.json').devDependencies
{
  '@semantic-release/changelog': '^6.0.0',
  '@semantic-release/git': '^10.0.0',
  chai: '^4.2.0',
  karma: '^6.0.2',
  'karma-chai': '^0.1.0',
  'karma-chrome-launcher': '^3.1.0',
  'karma-coverage': '^2.0.3',
  'karma-firefox-launcher': '^2.0.0',
  'karma-ie-launcher': '^1.0.0',
  'karma-jasmine': '^4.0.0',
  'karma-mocha': '^2.0.1',
  mocha: '^9.0.0',
  nyc: '^15.0.1',
  requirejs: '^2.3.6',
  'semantic-release': '^18.0.0',
  standard: '^16.0.0'
}
> Object.keys(require('./package.json').devDependencies)
[
  '@semantic-release/changelog',
  '@semantic-release/git',
  'chai',
  'karma',
  'karma-chai',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-firefox-launcher',
  'karma-ie-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-mocha',
  'mocha',
  'nyc',
  'requirejs',
  'semantic-release',
  'standard'
]
>
```